# How do I use a converter with a checkbox?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following checkbox in my XAML:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="DisplayPlateGapPoints" Content="Display Plate Gap Points" IsChecked="True"/>
```

I also have another control with an Opacity property. I want to set the opacity based on whether the checkbox is checked or unchecked (via the converter). I have tried this, but I get an exception at run time:

```
Opacity="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=DisplayPlateGapPoints, Converter={DynamicResource boolOpacityConverter}}"
```

The exception is as follows:

```
A 'DynamicResourceExtension' cannot be set on the Converter property of type 'Binding'
```

The converter itself is defined in another XAML file as follows:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
     <converters:BoolOpacityConverter    x:Key="boolOpacityConverter" />
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the exception? Where did you create the converter instance?

Comment: @H.B. - Updated question to include more information.

Comment: As the exception says you cannot use DynamicResource with non-dependency properties, why can't you use a StaticResource? It's not like the converter will ever change.

Comment: @H.B. - The XAML file in my question is loaded from a database at runtime. The converter is defined in another XAML file. When I use StaticResource I get an exception stating the resource named boolOpacityConverter cannot be found.

Comment: Why don't you create the converter in the same file? Shouldn't be too much of an overhead.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `StaticResource` instead of a `DynamicResource`, i.e.:

```
Opacity="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=DisplayPlateGapPoints, Converter={StaticResource boolOpacityConverter}}"
```

And make sure that the other XAML file is referenced through a resource dictionary, either in app.xaml or the target XAML file.